# Rails 3: Form within a loop?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a todo list and i'm basically trying to allow users to tick a checkbox and mark it as complete with ajax however I'm having some real trouble knowing how to specify that I want to edit 'tasks' (within a 'list') in my controller.

Currently my loop reveals all the 'tasks' for a 'list'. But when I try to add in a form with my checklist I get the error:

```
Couldn't find Task without an ID
```

Not sure how best to declare that I want to display all 'tasks' for that 'list' but I also want to allow users to edit each task within that list.

Here is my view:

```
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %> 


<%= form_for task, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box 'complete', :class => 'submittable' %> 
  <%= f.label :complete %>
<% end %>


<tr><td><h3><%=task.description %></h3></td><%=task.complete%><td></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Edit Task',edit_list_task_path(@list, task), :id => "edit_#{task.id}",:class=>"btn info" %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Delete Task', list_task_path(@list, task), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :id => "delete_#{task.id}", :class=>"btn danger "%></td></tr>

</tr>

<%end%>
```

And my controller:

```
  def index
    @tasks = @list.tasks
    @task = @list.tasks.find()
    @task.update_attributes params[:task]

 end
```

**Update:**

Made change in line with below comment. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
<%= form_for task, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= form_for @task, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

I.e. replace `@task` with `task`.

I don't know if this fixes your problem, but at least that's a visible typo.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I didn't spot that but I'm still having the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller, When you Say .find(), You need to pass the ID of the task.